# How to get a date in YYYY-MM-DD format from a TSQL datetime field?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I retrieve a date from SQL Server in `YYYY-MM-DD` format? I need this to work with SQL Server 2000 and up. Is there a simple way to perform this in SQL Server or would it be easier to convert it programmatically after I retrieve the result set?

I've read the [CAST and CONVERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) on Microsoft Technet, but the format I want isn't listed and changing the date format isn't an option.

Comment: The BOL description for 126 is a bit confusion (never found an explanation for "T").

Comment: The "T" separates the date from the time.  [See ISO 8601 on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 491, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126)
```

Limiting the size of the varchar chops of the hour portion that you don't want.

Comment: No, but some clients have issues with the fixed length.

Comment: This post comes up in Google for converting to YYYYMMDD - so that one is: CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),112)

Comment: This didn't work for me, suggestion above w/ a code 112 did. Thanks @NealWalters

Comment: The list of integer-codes for output styles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Code 126 is good for dates such as a date of birth in YYYY-mm-dd format: CONVERT(char(10), pat_dob , 126) as pat_dob

Comment: Syntax for CONVERT:  
`CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )`  then you want to use the style code for how you want the datetime to be formatted as per the [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)    (make sure you look under date and time styles.)

Comment: sql2014 CONVERT(date, GETDATE(), 126)

Comment: trimming of time component was what I was looking for. Thanks Mate!

Comment: Arbitrary integer codes for formats? Seriously, Microsoft? I hope the guy that created this "API" is roasting in hell now. Or worse: Forced to use his own API!
But thanks for pointing out, very helpful!

Answer (score 169):

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 100) -- mon dd yyyy hh:mmAM

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) -- mm/dd/yyyy – 10/02/2008                  

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 102) -- yyyy.mm.dd – 2008.10.02           

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 103) -- dd/mm/yyyy

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 104) -- dd.mm.yyyy

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 105) -- dd-mm-yyyy

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 106) -- dd mon yyyy

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 107) -- mon dd, yyyy

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) -- hh:mm:ss

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 109) -- mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmmAM (or PM)

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 110) -- mm-dd-yyyy

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 111) -- yyyy/mm/dd

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 112) -- yyyymmdd

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 113) -- dd mon yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmm

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 114) -- hh:mm:ss:mmm(24h)

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 120) -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h)

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 121) -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm

SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 126) -- yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.mmm
```

Comment: Thanks, only change 'yyyy-mm-dd' sections to 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

Comment: @MohsenNajafzadeh In this case Imran is only listing the date format string as a comment, so whether the month is capitalized is irrelevant; readers should know "month" is meant here rather than "minute" from the context of the question.

Answer (score 133):

Starting with **SQL Server 2012** (original question is for 2000):

`SELECT FORMAT(GetDate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: This is the sane flexible way to do date/time in recent SQL versions using Dotnet standard formats.  

Remember to capitalize month MM to distinguish from minutes.  [All date time formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: FORMAT runs (usually) 43 times slower than CONVERT.  I strong recommend that you never (and I don't use that word often) use FORMAT.

Answer (score 37):

The form you are after is listed in the books online documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(SQL.80).aspx

For example, try the following:

```
select convert(varchar,getDate(),120)
select convert(varchar(10),getDate(),120)
```

Comment: If you take the default, in this case, you get the time value - the entire format for format 120 is 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss'.  By explicitly declaring the length, it is trimmed to the format you specified in yout original note - 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

Answer (score 27):

The `convert` function with the format specifier 120 will give you the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", so you just have to limit the length to 10 to get only the date part:

```
convert(varchar(10), theDate, 120)
```

However, formatting dates is generally better to do in the presentation layer rather than in the database or business layer. If you return the date formatted from the database, then the client code has to parse it to a date again if it needs to do any calculations on it.

Example in C#:

```
theDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 13):

For YYYYMMDD try

```
select convert(varchar,getDate(),112)
```

I have only tested on SQLServer2008.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure why the simplest way has been ignored/omitted in the answers above:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GetDate(),'yyyy-MM-dd');--= 2020-01-02

SELECT FORMAT(GetDate(),'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss');-- = 02 Jan 2020 08:08:08
```

I prefer the second one because whichever language you speak, you will understand what date it is!

Also SQL Server always 'understands' it when you send that to your save procedure, regardless of which regional formats are set in the computers - I always use full year (yyyy), month name (MMM) and 24 hour format (capital HH) for hour in my programming.

Comment: It should continue to be ignored because it's a good 27 times slower than CONVERT. ;)

Comment: @JeffModen I need to update 2000 rows. Performance is not an issue in this situation. Answers that are less performant shouldn't be omitted purely because they are less performant. This is far more readable than using some magic int.

Comment: @ShinyShark - Heh.. you don't realize it but performance is always an issue because people will use such performance challenged answers for bigger things.

Comment: @JeffModen No they won't. Source: I didn't. Don't gatekeep simplicity for the sake of gaining some unrequired performance. The difference between 0.0001 and 0.0002 is 100%, but in the context of the situation it is negligible.

Comment: @shinyshark - Just because you didn't doesn't mean others won't.  It's not "gatekeeping".  It's called supporting the correct method to do something.

Comment: @shinyshark: Just a thought: shouldn't programming adapt to human nature? With all the advances made in memory, processing speed, AI, why shouldn't little things like these just be adapted to human "forms"? I think someone needs to go to work and re-look at this age-old date problem that has plagued humanity like forever!

Answer (score 7):

One other way...

```
CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(yyyy, @datetime)) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(mm, @datetime)) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(dd, @datetime))
```

Comment: This will create 1 digit dates as in 8/3/2012 if you want 2 digit mm/dd you need to left pad the dates. RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(yyyy, @datetime)), 2)  for example

Answer (score 7):

For those who would want the time part as well (I did), the following snippet may help

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 120) -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h)
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 121) -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 126) -- yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.mmm
                              --example -- 2008-10-02T10:52:47.513
```

Answer (score 6):

```
replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 111), '/','-')
```

Will also do trick without "chopping anything off".

Comment: I prefer this version to avoid "year 9999" bugs associated with the convert(varchar(10)...) version.

Answer (score 6):

In case someone wants to do it the **other way around** and finds this.

```
select convert(datetime, '12.09.2014', 104)
```

This converts a string in the German date format to a datetime object.

**Why 104?** See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You may also use. This is by using the new datatype `DATE`. May not work in all previous versions, but greatly simplified to use in later version.

```
SELECT CAST(getdate() AS DATE)
SELECT LEFT(CAST(getdate() AS DATE), 7)
```

Answer (score 5):

In your cast and convert link, use style 126 thus:

`CONVERT (varchar(10), DTvalue, 126)`

This truncates the time. Your requirement to have it in yyyy-mm-dd means it must be a string datatype and datetime.

Frankly though, I'd do it on the client unless you have good reasons not to.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use it as a date instead of a `varchar` again afterwards, don't forget to convert it back:

```
select convert(datetime,CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126))
```

Comment: wouldn't this convert it back to the system default format?

Answer (score 3):

From SQL Server 2008 you can do this: `CONVERT(date,getdate())`

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 23)`

Comment: why use NVARCHAR(20)? could there be special characters in there?

Comment: I prever to use UNICODE. Mos of my projects international ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
CONVERT(char(10),GETDATE(),126)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Code,Description FROM TABLE

-- This will Include only date part of 14th March 2010. Any date with date companents will not be considered.
WHERE ID= 1 AND FromDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-02-14', 126) AND ToDate <= DATEADD(dd, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-03-14', 126))

-- This will Include the whole day of 14th March 2010
--WHERE ID= 1 AND FromDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-02-14', 126) AND ToDate < DATEADD(dd, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-03-14', 126))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a CASE statement for each of the convert / cast functions always works for me:

> Please replace tableXXXXY with your table name, and issueDate_dat with the name of your datetime field in that table:

```
SELECT  issueDate_dat, CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(yyyy, issuedate_dat))  AS issueDateYYYY
, CASE WHEN (len(CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(mm, issuedate_dat))) < 2) THEN '0' +CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(mm, issuedate_dat)) ELSE CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(mm, issuedate_dat)) END AS  issueDateMM
, CASE WHEN (len(CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(dd, issuedate_dat))) <2) THEN '0' +CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(dd, issuedate_dat)) ELSE CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(dd, issuedate_dat)) END AS issueDateDD
FROM            tableXXXXY
```

Hope this was helpful. chagbert.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me, simple and effective (with 126 too)

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), CAST(GETDATE() as date), 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR", true);

cmdGetPaymentStatement.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pStartDate", DateTime.Parse("22/12/2017", culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal)).IsNullable = true;
```

Comment: Code above is used for providing a store procedure to parameter in the form of mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Seems unnecessary to do any strange things, if you want your date to be seperated by slash.
Just escape it with a backslash. Otherwise you will end up with a dot.

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy\/MM');
```

Tested on SQL Server 2016

Comment: You should test it for performance.  FORMAT is generally 43 times slower than even a complicated CONVERT.

Answer (score -1):

If your source date format is all messed up, try something along the lines of:

```
select
convert(nvarchar(50),year(a.messedupDate))+'-'+
(case when len(convert(nvarchar(50),month(a.messedupDate)))=1 
    then '0'+ convert(nvarchar(50),month(a.messedupDate))+'-' 
    else convert(nvarchar(50),month(a.messedupDate)) end)+
(case when len(convert(nvarchar(50),day(a.messedupDate)))=1 
    then '0'+ convert(nvarchar(50),day(a.messedupDate))+'-'
    else convert(nvarchar(50),day(a.messedupDate)) end) 
from messytable a
```

Answer (score -1):

As string processing is expensive, and FORMAT more so, I am surprised that Asher/Aaron Dietz response is not higher, if not top; the question is seeking ISO 8601 date, and isn't specifically requesting it as a string type.

The most efficient method would be any of these (I've included the answer Asher/Aaron Dietz have already suggested for completeness):

**All versions**

```
select  cast(getdate() as date)
select  convert(date, getdate())
```

**2008 and higher**

```
select  convert(date, current_timestamp)
```

**ANSI SQL equivalent 2008 and higher**

```
select  cast(current_timestamp as date)
```

References:

https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_current_timestamp.asp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timestamp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -1):

change GetDate() to any format as String:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GetDate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: The question asks for a date, not a datetime string. There are *several* answers already that show how to convert to `date` or an ISO8601 datetime string