# SQL convert date to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql-server, date

How would you convert a date in the format of:

```
2012-10-16 07:44:22.000
```

to this format:

```
2012-10-16
```

And no just making the varchar(10) wont work as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889629/how-to-get-a-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-from-a-tsql-datetime-field) suggests, because I have to compare them and I can't do it with that method. Also [nowhere does it give me the](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) value to do that type of conversion.

This is as close as I've come:

```
declare @DATE DATETIME = '2012-10-16 00:00:000'
SELECT  Convert(varchar(20), @DATE,105)
```

Result = 16-10-2012

Comment: What do you mean which SQL is it? REAALY? -1? REALY? What did i do wrong?

Comment: You spelled "really" wrong. ;)

Comment: Just FYI: SQL is a *language*. Many products use it. And @wallyk meant to enquire about the specific product you are using, which turns out to be SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know there was that big of a difference between the SQL languages (syntax wise)

Comment: Yes, many things are vendor specific. So always including your database type and version in the tags, will yield faster more accurate answers :)

Comment: *because i have to compare them.*  Compare them how? Date comparisons should be done with date/time objects, not strings.

Comment: Thanks, will defiantly keep that in mind for my next post. So not Even when you just want to see the results of a certain day? '2012-11-39' = '2012-11-39'

Comment: @Ruan - No. As long as the target column is a date/time you should use a date/time object. You can truncate the time, just cast it back to a date/time object before the comparison.

Comment: Thank you, Will remember that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @DATE DATETIME = '2012-10-16 00:00:000'
SELECT  REPLACE(Convert(varchar(20), @DATE,102), '.', '-')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6764)

**[Here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)'s** an overview of the date formats in SQL Server.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@date, 120)
--Gives: yyyy-mm-dd
```

Comment: no actually that wont help me.. Varchar(10) wont work for me. (see question)

Comment: Check out this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6767). This works on sql server. Not sure why you say it isn't

Comment: Ah yea you are right, it did work, my comparison was just out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

mysql you can use select CURDATE();

it returns the current date (yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: Curdate() returns the current date, its fine but it doesn't answer the question. Try to `convert` the date to the desired format