# Change the format of date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, date-format

I have a column called `purchaseDate` of type `DATE`. I want to write a query that returns `purchaseDate` in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

I'm having trouble doing this while using a between function. Here's my code

```
select *
from purchaseOrders
where purchaseDate between '20-09-18' and '20-10-18'
```

This is the result I expect to get:

```
purchaseDate
------------
2018-09-20
2018-09-21
2018-09-22
2018-10-19
2018-10-20
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Sqlite **doesn't have** a DATE type. Refer to https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Whatever value you're storing in your purchaseDate column is what it is. If you want it to be `YYYY-MM-DD` that's what you need to store in it and use when comparing/ordering by the column. (Or another recognized date/time format and convert as needed)

Comment: @Shawn, thanks for pointing that out. That means the database being used is SQL Server. I don't actually have the database, I'm just answering a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10), purchaseDate, 120) AS 'Purchase Date'
from purchaseOrders
where purchaseDate
between '20-09-18' and '20-10-18';
```

More here: [How to get a date in YYYY-MM-DD format from a TSQL datetime field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889629/how-to-get-a-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-from-a-tsql-datetime-field/889660)

**Edit 2:**

SQLite requires date to be in YYYY-mm-dd format or other recognizable formats in this post:
[SQL Select between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates)

You can simply do this:

```
select *
from purchaseOrders
where purchaseDate
between '2018-09-18' and '2018-10-18'
```

Comment: Thanks for this Gauravsa. I'll take a look at the link.

Comment: Thanks again Gauravsa. The first part of you answer is actually okay, because the database is actually being run on SQL Server.

Comment: Yeah, the convert use a value of 106 (which is dd mon yy), is it possible to have it as 120 (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss), with the " hh:mi:ss" removed? If so, how do you do it?

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks a lot for the help Gauravsa. One last thing, do I not need the REPLACE clause?

Comment: If you simply need '2012-06-18' then 120 gives you, no need of replace.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [stftime()](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/strftime.php) in your query:

```
select *
from purchaseOrders
where purchaseDate between strftime(%s, '20-09-18') and strftime(%s, '20-10-18')
```

> The syntax for the strftime function in SQLite is:
>
> `strftime(format, timestring [, modifier1, modifier2, ... modifier_n ])`

There are also some other alternatives discussed here:

[SQL Select between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So the first parameter converts 20-09-18 to 2018-09-20? I ask because [in this link](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/sqlite/sqlite-strftime-function), it says the second parameter has to be in a certain format, will that be the current format or the format you intend to convert it to?

Comment: can the query you wrote also be used for SQL Server?