# How to get date column value identical when i have different formats of value in same column

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala, hue

I have a hadoop table with date column having values like below

```
Date
03/22/2015 12:07:41.000000
23-MAR-15 03.25.17.000000000 PM
```

can you help me how can I make the values as identical while loading into my staging table.

I want output like

```
Date
03/22/2015
03/23/2015
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT` function.

To get MM/DD/YYYY format `SELECT convert(varchar(10), YourColumn, 101)`

And also you can use other value for the third parameter to get another format.
[See here for more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889629/how-to-get-a-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-from-a-tsql-datetime-field)

I hope it works in Hadoop.

Comment: yup it works but the asci code shows different result, 23-MAR-15  where i need 03/23/2015.. i tried

Comment: i am trying to write the query in impala  as like below
SELECT Strleft(profl.createdate,10) from infa_mdm_c_bo_prod_profl profl limit 100

and below is my result.. 
01-FEB-08 
03-APR-11 
02/21/2019
03/20/2015

i want to get output as 
01/02/2008
04/03/2011 
02/21/2019
03/20/2015