# Get last day of previous month in yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-date-functions

How do I get the last day of the previous month in `yyyy-mm-dd` format?

This is what I have tried, however I don't want the seconds showing. Only YYYY-MM-DD:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Comment: A date format is only viable if you are displaying it as a varchar data type (date/datetimes are bytes and have no format). Just wrap all your expression in a `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), <expression>, 120)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a date in YYYY-MM-DD format from a TSQL datetime field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889629/how-to-get-a-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-from-a-tsql-datetime-field)

Comment: Probably using EOMONTH is another option - `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1), 23)`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`EOMONTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function along with `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(EOMONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -1), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

The `-1` in the above example means subtract 1 month from argument 1 (there is no need for `DATEADD`).

Answer (score 1):

Convert it into date only format

```
SELECT convert(date,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)),103)
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),  DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)), 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this which is popular :

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)),120)
```

[Live demo](https://rextester.com/ABFB15259)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)),23)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this, due to newer versions of SQL supporting it:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATE,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MM,-1,GETDATE())),103)
```

Code is shorter to accomplish the same task...