# Get first day of previous month in YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-date-functions

How do I get the first day of previous month in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

I have tried this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 120)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674607/get-last-day-of-previous-month-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format/57675402#57675402)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`EOMONTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function for this. This function is supposed to return the end of month so add one day to result:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2)) -- returns 2019-07-01 on 2019-08-28 01:02:03.004
```

Wrap the above expression inside `FORMAT(..., 'yyyy-MM-dd')` to *format* the result.

Comment: Worth noting that the value doesn't have a "format"; that's for the presentation layer to decide. For SSMS, its default tends to be `yyyy-MM-dd` for the `date,` data type.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)),23)
```

Output:

```
2019-07-31
```