# How do I convert a datetime column format from yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datetime-format

I have a datetime column where the date is stored as `yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss` but I want to change it to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

For example, **09 Nov 2019** should be **2019-11-09** but it dsiplays as 2019-09-11.

I've tried CAST/CONVERT, but they didn't change the format.

Comment: there is no format for a datetime object so I'm assuming the data type of the column is (n)varchar, yes?

Comment: It's a datetime column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a date in YYYY-MM-DD format from a TSQL datetime field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889629/how-to-get-a-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-from-a-tsql-datetime-field)

Comment: what are your language and dateformat settings?  you can check using `DBCC USEROPTIONS;`

Comment: If it's `datetime`, you **can't** chaneg the format, @Matt, it doesn't have one. The format the value is *displayed* in is determined by your application layer not the RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 23)

declare @t date='09 Nov 2019'
select convert(varchar, @t, 23)
```

Output:-

```
2019-11-09
```

Date format 120

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 120)
```

Output:

```
2019-11-11 16:46:26
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's good for the date, but what about the time part?

Comment: You're missing the length of your `varchar`. but the problem now is that the OP's data is no longer a `datetime`; which is a far larger problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following format:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @YourDate, 106)
```

Working query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '09 Nov 2019', 106) -- it will return 2019-11-09
```

If you are expecting the result in the `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format, then

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CONVERT(DATETIME, '09 Nov 2019', 106), 120) -- will result 2019-11-09 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your DEFAULT_LANGUAGE format of database

try this :

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'default language', N'0'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
ALTER LOGIN [myuser] WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
GO
```

Change [us_english] if necessary with your prefert langage, but be carrefull if your database are already used….

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  It pointed me in the right direction for what I was looking for.

My solution was (probably wrong, but works)...

```
,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(8), [LeadSentTime], 112), 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(8), [LeadSentTime], 112), 7, 2) + '-'  + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(8), [LeadSentTime], 112), 5, 2) + ' ' +
  CONVERT(char(12), [LeadSentTime], 14)
```

This gave the required result - 2019-11-09 10:41:55 instead of 2019-09-11 10:41:55

Comment: Did you read the documentation for convert and look at all the styles? Does not style 121 do exactly this?