# Unsure of date format 1200819 but need to convert to 08-19-20

Tags: date

The column is a nvachar(20).

select [shipment_posted_date_arch]
FROM [RxIntegrity].[dbo].[DiscrepancyReport_Receipts]

When I pull this, the date is in this format of 1200819 for that column. I need to convert to normal date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a date in YYYY-MM-DD format from a TSQL datetime field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889629/how-to-get-a-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-from-a-tsql-datetime-field)

Comment: none of those show the century code, i'm not sure what to do

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work:
cast(convert(nvarchar(20), (19000000 + CONVERT(int, shipment_posted_date_arch))) as date)